# Push values into array by dynamically created input id

Tags: jquery

I want an array of all values from dynamically created input ids.

There are multiple dropdowns having a unique id which is created dynamically. I want only ids value and one array so that I can pass it in PHP code for further processing.

```
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_1" value="33252" name="violation_template_notices[1][ar_code_id]">
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_2" value="33253" name="violation_template_notices[2][ar_code_id]">
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_3" value="33254" name="violation_template_notices[3][ar_code_id]">
```

Expected result:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ar_codes" value="33252,33253,33254">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways you can achieve this:

## Approach #1

```js
var arCodes = [];

$("input[name^='violation_template_notices']")
  .each(function(input) {
    // collect the input values into an array
    arCodes.push($(this).val());
  });

// Join the values of the array and put it to the text field.
$('input[name="ar_codes"]').val(arCodes.join(','))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_1" value="33252" name="violation_template_notices[1][ar_code_id]">
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_2" value="33253" name="violation_template_notices[2][ar_code_id]">
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_3" value="33254" name="violation_template_notices[3][ar_code_id]">

<input type="text" name="ar_codes" value="">
```

## Approach #2

```js
const arCodes = Array.from(
  $("input[name^='violation_template_notices']"),
  input => input.value
).join(", ");

$('input[name="ar_codes"]').val(arCodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_1" value="33252" name="violation_template_notices[1][ar_code_id]">
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_2" value="33253" name="violation_template_notices[2][ar_code_id]">
<input type="hidden" id="selected_charge_code_3" value="33254" name="violation_template_notices[3][ar_code_id]">

<input type="text" name="ar_codes" value="">
```